# Angular File Upload Callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

Really struggling with this at the moment so if anyone had any advice that would be fantastic. Pretty sure it's a case of me over complicating something simple but we'll see!

Using the following to upload files to a server

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API

I am creating several instances of a file uploader for certain types of files (can't just use one as I need different upload URLs for each)

So I then have a list like

```
var uploaders = [a list of file object uploaders]
```

What I want to do is iterate over the list, call `uploadAll()` on each one, then once the files for each have been uploaded, continue the script.

The problem is I don't think the `uploadAll` function implements a `promise`, so when I try the following code the rest of the script continues on before the files have been successfully uploaded.

Heres what I have

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

var uploaders = [my list of object uploaders]

var allUploads = uploaders.map(function(uploaders) {
    var singleUploadPromise = uploaders.uploadAll();
    return singleUploadPromise;
}); 



$q.all(allUploads).then(function() {    
    console.log('Finished uploading all files')
    deferred.resolve('Finished uploading all files');
}, function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

The files get uploaded but the rest of the script carries out before they do. When I

```
console.log(allUploads)
```

I get a list of `undefined` items. So clearly I am going wrong here but I am unsure as to how to move forward.

Comment: I'm not the best at ES6 but I don't think that uploadAll() returns anything https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/src/services/FileUploader.js#L134

Answer (score 1):

Based on looking at the code for the file uploader, .uploadAll() does not return anything, but it does have callback .onCompleteAll(). So, you could create a deffered object that you resolve in the callback function of each uploader's call to uploadAll().

```
        var uploaders = [my list of object uploaders];

        var allUploads = uploaders.map(function(uploader) {
            // you need one deffered object per uploader
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // set up an onCompleteAll callback for each uploader
            uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
                deferred.resolve('onCompleteAll');
            };

            // call uploadAll on each uploader
            uploader.uploadAll();

            return deferred;
    }); 


    var combinedUploads = $q.all(allUploads).then(function() {    
            console.log('Finished uploading all files');
    }, function(error) {
            console.log('error!');
    });

    return combinedUploads.promise; // assuming this was in another function
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, for sure looks like a possible solution. Will let you know how I go when I get a chance!

Comment: Great! I'm very curious to know if that was what you needed.  I can tinker with it some more if that doesn't work.

Comment: Any example for Angular 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

it`s the uploadAll() method that is causing your problem i guess.